# Term to designate employee "current status"

Tags: terminology

Given the items below:

- On vacation
- On sick leave
- On maternity/paternity leave
- Employed
- Retired

Related to a employee, what term nominates or best describes this group of items? Can i name it "employee status" or something?

Comment: Sure, it is "status". (You really don't have to sat "employee status" = just "status" is fine.)

Comment: Why the word "retired"? Why not "under retirement"? Frankly, I'm not familiar with the expressions "under vacation," "under medical license," etc., unless you're using the word "under" to indicate that the labelling of employee status should be categorized (or filed under) vacation, medical "leave(?)," pregnancy "leave"(?), normal activity, and retirement. Don

Comment: Sorry, the word "under" was a translation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "under" terms are not natural to me, but that could be a regionalism. The following terms are more common, at least in northeastern US english:

- On vacation
- On sick leave
- On maternity/paternity leave
- Employed
- Retired

Given these changes, the term "Employment Status" would be preferable to "Employee Status." "Employee status" would be more general, and could include their job satisfaction, performance, etc.

"Employment status" does imply a global status, not a status in regard to any particular company. The government might track it, for instance. If you are looking for something to keep track of the individuals within one organization, let me know and I can brainstorm something appropriate.

Comment: [Employment Status](https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/overview) in UK points to a different meaning. Is there something similar for USA?

Comment: What is the meaning in the UK?